# How to register application module when using grunt-angular-templates?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, gruntjs, karma-runner

[Using grunt-angular-templates](https://github.com/ericclemmons/grunt-angular-templates), My generated file to register templates on the $templateCache looks like this:

```
 angular.module('MyLittleApp').run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
```

But when I run my tak in Karma it says,

```
Module 'MyLittleApp' is not available!"
```

Tests work normally without using the template cache method. It is required so that $httpBackend requests do not get intercepted for template fetches.

Comment: Just checking if it helps: is your `MyLittleApp` module itself actually defined anywhere. If it's not, you'd change `angular.module('MyLittleApp')` to `angular.module('MyLittleApp', [])`.